# Docker container with Postgres image repeatedly FATAL errors

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I've been running a `docker-compose.yml` file for a week or so now on a remote DO Droplet (Ubuntu) but suddenly I am seeing a constant stream of error messages after I run `docker compose up`:

```
database  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
database  | 
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:35.510 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014) 13.2.1 20231014, 64-bit
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:35.510 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:35.511 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:35.536 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:35.570 UTC [25] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-03-09 05:02:46 UTC
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:35.619 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:37.901 UTC [29] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:37.901 UTC [29] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
database  |     Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:39.028 UTC [30] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:39.028 UTC [30] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
database  |     Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:40.207 UTC [31] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:40.207 UTC [31] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
database  |     Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:41.332 UTC [32] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
database  | 2024-03-09 05:05:41.332 UTC [32] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
database  |     Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

This is what my `docker-compose.yml` file looks like (I have a .env file in the  same directory with the corresponding values):

```
version: "3.4"

services:
    database:
      image: postgres
      container_name: ${DATABASE_HOST}
      ports:
        - ${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
        POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      volumes:
        - ~/apps/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I'm able to connect just fine to the database via pgAdmin4 on my Windows desktop (via the remote) using the `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` credentials and everything works as it should.

I've tried adding a `postgres` user to the database with login privileges but the error message just changes to:

```
database  | 2024-03-09 05:14:54.013 UTC [73] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
database  | 2024-03-09 05:14:54.013 UTC [73] DETAIL:  User "postgres" has no password assigned.
```

If I add a password then it simply becomes:

```
database  | 2024-03-09 05:15:02.139 UTC [80] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
database  | 2024-03-09 05:15:02.139 UTC [80] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

I have inspected the `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf` file in the container and its settings are as follows:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all scram-sha-256
```

I did have a version of `postgresql` installed on the remote but I uninstalled it earlier (`dpkg -l | grep postgres` returns nothing and I removed the postgres user). I think there is another program either on the remote or in the postgres container that is trying to connect via pgAdmin or something but I cannot for the life of me find the source. The postgres container does contain a `postgres` user, and I was actually able to successfully `psql` into the postgresql instance running on the container after I setup the postgres user, but the error messages kept coming. Can someone please help me figure out what's happening and get the error messages to stop. Did I miss some basic step setting up the database volume?

Comment: Some miscreant is trying to guess your password. You can block unknown IP addresses at the firewall if you want.

Comment: Is this really the case even though my container is hosted on a remote digital ocean droplet that requires an ssh key to login? Do I need to be worried about the remote's security?

Comment: It certainly appears to be the case.  Just because you need an ssh key to login over ssh, doesn't mean you need one to connect to PostgreSQL.  You could configure it to need that (with a tunnel and a firewall) but you haven't described doing so, and the evidence suggests you haven't.  Whether you need to be concerned depends on how unguessable those passwords you assigned are.

Comment: Yeah I think you were right on the money as concerning as that is. I reset a bunch of my passwords and set up a firewall option to allow only ssh connections to my droplet and I haven't seen the error messages since. Thank you!